# For 'element' in 'list' (but not including element X)

Tags: python-3.x

I need to run through a list but miss out a specific element in said list, is there a quick way to do this?

```
list = ['X','Y','Z']
for element in list (but not including element 'X'):
    print(element)

>>>Y
>>>Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seq = ['X','Y','Z']
for element in seq:
    if element == 'X':
        continue
    print(element)
```